# What's the point of AC fan speed?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

Does higher fan speed make the room cooler? But then, if the thermostat is set at a certain degree doesn't the AC keep the room at that temperature regardless of what speed the fan is set on?

What exactly is the purpose of being able to change the speed of the AC fan?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, efficiency.  A variable speed motor can operate at a slower speed when less cooling is needed.  Lower speed means less power used, which saves money.

Comment: There are other benefits with variable speed blower motors, as described in other answers, but this is the correct answer. Prior to advancing tech that made speed control easier/cheaper, there was no economic benefit/payoff, now there is.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this website](https://nhsaves.com/blog/go-with-the-flow-circulating-fans-save-energy/#:%7E:text=Air%20circulation%20saves%20energy%20year,a%20more%20uniform%20building%20temperature.), "Air circulation saves energy year-round by reducing the need for space heating and cooling." If your goal is to even the temperature throughout your home (opposed to creating pockets of relative heat near the ceilings and relative cold near the floor), the more air you can circulate (by increasing your fan speed),  the better. Basically, when you circulate your air, you are mixing it so it becomes a homogeneous temperature. This effect is greatly compounded via well designed central air systems that don't just move air around in one room...but move it constantly throughout your home.

By increasing a ceiling fan speed, you increase circulation in that room. By increasing your central air fan speeds (and setting them to always run), the air throughout your home will more effectively have similar temperatures. There are pros and cons to this depending on a number of factors (winter, summer, insulation, costs, etc) that are well detailed on [this website](https://trusthomesense.com/blog/pros-cons-continuously-running-hvac-fan/).

Finally, many people increase fan speeds simply to enhance the cooling sensation that our skin feels when evaporation increases. This is desirable when it's uncomfortably hot, and you want to feel cooler (via the physics of heat transfer). [Here's a quick article describing how that works](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/57774/how-does-fan-work-cool-you#:%7E:text=A%20fan%2C%20or%20a%20breeze,surrounding%20air%20simply%20by%20convection.&text=The%20breeze%20from%20the%20fan,process%2C%20effectively%20cooling%20you%20off.).

Comment: You did a good job of including a relevant comment from your first link, please include some relevant details from the other two, in case those links go dead.